# Applying an electrical field to a particle in Ansys HFSS

Tags: simulation, electromagnetic, s-parameters, ads

Does Ansys HFSS have the ability to show the applied electrical field to a particle?

I designed a coplanar wave guide in this software, something like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epzH6ST1OVg).

Is it possible to put a particle between the electrodes to check the parameter variation?

Is there any tutorial about it on the web?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If you are simulating electrical fields outside of material, HFSS is good. In other words, if you're simulating wave propagation inside metal wave guides, the electromagnetic field around a particle, etc. you can use HFSS.

But as HFSS is based on FEM, it does not give good results when you're simulating wave propagation inside material, especially when the material constants are not consistent.

For such simulations FDTD gives better results.

Besides CST and FDTD simulation software, there's an open-source project called [Meep](https://github.com/NanoComp/meep), which is worth a try.